# How to use the same published PowerBI report with different data sources link?

Tags: powerbi, m, powerbi-datasource

I am a newbie with PowerBI and I have a need to use the same report created with different link sources, the sources have the same table structure.

I use Other - Web as da data source and use a link like this

http://db.other.com.br/nahar/infinity/rest/entitygrupo

where infinity is the database, and I have many others:

http://db.other.com.br/nahar/rachu/rest/entitygrupo

the data retrieved is exactly the same.

I would like to find a way to somehow keep the report intact with no need to create one just to change the source, since I have many databases. It would be perfect if I could use the same published link and pass some parameter that change the link in use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Parameters and templates](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/deep-dive-into-query-parameters-and-power-bi-templates/) in Power BI serve this use case exactly.

Assume we have the following data source for demo purpose:

https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1

https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/2

Where `1` and `2` are equivalent to the database names (`infinity` and `rachu`) in your data source.

The query will be like:

```
let
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1")),
    #"Converted to Table" = Record.ToTable(Source)
in
    #"Converted to Table"
```

Now we can create a new parameter for `database_name`:

[image: new parameter]

[image: database_name]

Then we can go to `Advanced Editor` to modify the query and parameterize the data source:

```
let
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/" & database_name)),
    #"Converted to Table" = Record.ToTable(Source)
in
    #"Converted to Table"
```

[image: advanced editor]

You'll notice there are no changes at the moment.

[image: parameterize]

Create a simple table to display the data (id 1):

[image: table 1]

And then we can export the report as a Power BI template:

[image: power bi template]

If you open the template file, you will be asked to input the values for parameters. Let's try `2` for `database_name` and click load:

[image: enter parameters]

You'll see that the report is loaded with data coming from database 2 (id 2), and it has identical report layout as the first one:

[image: report 2]